# How to create a window (dialog like) inside a class library?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a dialog window inside a DLL. I've referenced the xaml assembly, but the problem happens with the "partial" keyword.

Somehow VS2010 is not identifying the .xaml and the .xaml.cs as a unique body... how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the references, a C# project that uses WPF needs additional project sub-types.  The easiest way to do this is to create a new project and select "WPF User Control Library" and then will set up everything correctly.

On the other hand, if you've already created your project, you can compare the csproj file to one created using the above instructions and manually edit in the ProjectTypeGuid section that is different.

Comment: I did that and I was still having no luck. If I created another project and then copy my dialog over, it would work, but not inside my modified project. It turns out that if you copy a wpf window from another project to a class library, you need to readjust the "Build Action" to page for the xaml file in question.

Comment: A trick that works in that situation is to use "Show all Files",  "Exclude from Project" the files and then "Include in Project" them back in and the project types/actions of the various files will usually get straightened out.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new DLL using the "Wpf Control Library" project